wifi channel change dropping wifi connection
I'm experiencing an issue with my Ubuntu 22.04 server losing its Wi-Fi connection and failing to reconnect when my router automatically changes its 5GHz channel. The logs below indicate the channel change that coincided with the loss of connection:
Oct 27 13:55:14 homeserver wpa_supplicant[666]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-STARTED-CHANNEL-SWITCH freq=5180 ht_enabled=1 ch_offset=1 ch_width=80 MHz cf1=5210 cf2=0
Oct 27 13:55:15 homeserver kernel: wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by d0:db:b7:97:39:c4
Oct 27 13:55:15 homeserver wpa_supplicant[666]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-CHANNEL-SWITCH freq=5180 ht_enabled=1 ch_offset=1 ch_width=80 MHz cf1=5210 cf2=0

I can confirm that the issue is related to the channel change. After checking the new channel that the router has switched to, I update the Netplan YAML configuration with the appropriate band: and channel: properties, apply the changes, and the connection is restored.
Could anyone please advise whether this is a software or hardware issue? Are there any settings I could adjust to ensure that the server's Wi-Fi can handle channel changes more effectively? Unfortunately, I cannot set the router to a fixed channel, as it is configured to operate in auto mode.
Thanks

You mention 22.04 & server, the Server ISOs default to the older kernel stack; so maybe an easy fix maybe switching to the newer HWE kernel stack (ie. change 22.04 5.15 kernel to 6.8).  If you can afford taking your system offline, you maybe able to try this out using live media without any change/install too. Providing specifics on your wifi hardware may have been helpful too.

If possible, it's preferable to run a server over wired ethernet. What hardware are you using? (update your question with these details)

Hi guiverc, I'm currently on kernel 6.8.0-47-generic. Device is a Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] (rev 10).
Hi moo, I know wireless is not ideal and I would love to be using ethernet but at the moment that is not possible for various reasons.

You mention server, where Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server uses the 5.15 kernel, so your system is probably modified; you have the option of trying the GA kernel stack which is used by Server installs as its seen as the more stable option (HWE which is at 6.8 is default for Desktop installs; Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server uses the 6.8 kernel, but you mentioned 22.04)

neofetch shows Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64. Going back to some of my notes I followed this guide for HWE https://ubuntu.com/kernel/lifecycle. I must of read somewhere that it was a good idea to do so, hope that wasn't a mistake, apart from this my server has been stable. Can I go back to the GA kernel? Is that even a good idea at this point.

running dpkg --list | grep linux-image shows
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-124-generic         5.15.0-124.134                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.8.0-47-generic           6.8.0-47.47~22.04.1                      amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                    5.15.0.124.124                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04          6.8.0-47.47~22.04.1                      amd64        Generic Linux kernel image

Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choice; with default set by install media (Desktop defaults to HWE as its better for newer graphics hardware, Server defaults to GA as stability is prized), but which you use is up to you, and neither is a mistake.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack can provide details; but I didn't say one kernel stack would be better; I suggested trying it using live media so nothing on your system was changed; and see if it's a problem with the other stack.. if it isn't you have an option for likely fix.

ok I understand. The other option I was thinking was plugging in a wireless adapter and see if it does the same thing. I figure if this is a problem with the current wireless another one may fix it. What do you think?

May be easier to change the router so it doesn't change channel by default
